# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown menu is floating right when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im facing a annoying problem where my Dropdown-Menus are floating to the right side when the menu is collapsed on small screens. 
I copied the navbar code from their example site and modified it to use it in my project and now I saw the styling problem. Maybe i removed something important here.

Here a Screenshot: [Image showing the float problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c98sb.png)

Has anyone an idea? Im new to bootstrap and need some help!

here the Code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default mainnav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">-</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?calc-classic=start">Angebot erstellen</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Vorlagen <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li><a href="index.php?vorlagen-restaurants"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></i> Restaurant</a></li>

            <li><a href="index.php?vorlagen-hotels"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Hotel</a></li>

            <li><a href="index.php?confirmation"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i> Confirm</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="index.php?invoices">RVw</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Kunden <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="index.php?kunden"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Alle Kunden</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?neukunde"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Kunde hinzufügen</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Einstellungen</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Hallo xyz ! <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="include/logout.php?logout">Ausloggen</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Show your custom CSS please.

Comment: Please **reproduce** the issue here.

Comment: For some reason the posted code snippet is working well. I tried with Chrome and Opera both browsers, and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured out i was still including an old css which had the same class name.. Removing this fixed the problem.